# QGIS expression - overlay function, using overlay function as filter

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, filter, overlay

I have a point layer with one field, `id` ranging from 0 to 9. I have a polygon that intersects some of the points, like so:

[image]

My aim is to use an expression to get the intersecting point with the highest value for `id`.

For demonstration purposes I use a Geometry Generator symbol layer on my *polygon* layer.

```
collect_geometries(
    overlay_intersects(
        'point_layer', 
        $geometry,
        filter:= id = array_max(overlay_intersects('point_layer', id))
    )
)
```

I expect there to be a single point at the location of the point in `point_layer` with the highest `id` (9). However, all intersecting points are returned.

[image]

When I test the expression I use for the filter as a standalone expression, it returns 9, as expected.

[image]

And when I hard-code the highest `id` value (9), I get the desired result:

```
collect_geometries(
    overlay_intersects(
        'point_layer', 
        $geometry,
        filter:= id = 9
    )
)
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a very elegant way, but I think it will work.

```
with_variable(
    'maxval',
    array_max(
        overlay_intersects(
            'point_layer', 
            "id"
        )
    ),
    array_filter(
        overlay_intersects(
            'point_layer', 
            array("id", $geometry)
        ),
        @element[0] = @maxval
    )[0][1]
)
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, indeed. However, it is returning `NULL`. (Without the `[0]` array index it returns an empty array). That seems strange. Evaluating `@maxval` without the second overlay expression returns `9` as expected.

Comment: Ok, very strange behavior of this expression.

Comment: Just for debug, remove the filter from the second overlay. To see if it still return an empty array.

Comment: Good idea to check. It's the expected array (using `[0]` gets the first point `id=0`).

Comment: So the problem is clearly the filter.

Comment: Try the update. Maybe using a different function to filter works.

Comment: That works. Took me a moment to see the logic, very creative! Thanks :)